# slots and signals for multithreading

Tags: multithreading, qt, pthreads

I have a job in pthread which prepares a data set for plotting. Then I need to display this data in a main window like a graph. How can I transfer the data set form the thread to the rendering widget which is in the main window.

I use slots and signals. What happens when my thread emits signal more frequently than the slot could receive it.

The problem is that I use `QMap*` to transfer the data set form one thread to another. And I need to be confident that slot finished its job and I can update this map in the job thread.

Comment: you dont have to use pointers with signals and slots. just copy the current state of the data.

Comment: You don't need to even copy the data since QMap uses implicit sharing: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html

Comment: Since you're using pthreads, are you manually calling processEvents() periodically? There is no event loop to call this for you so your signal/slots would not even be making it out of your pthread without doing so...

Comment: @g19fanatic Could you plz make an answer and explain what You mean?

Comment: I could add an answer, but it would not be answering your question. I will add additional information later on.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume you mean you have a job in 'QThread', not pthread (as in posix thread). In that case, you're right to use signals and slots to pass the data to the main thread for rendering.

How frequent is 'more frequently than the slot could receive it'? Have you tried it and are you having problems, or just speculating about something that you think may go wrong? If you are actually having a problem with sending too many signals, then batch up the data on the processing thread and send the batch periodically on a timer.

As for ensuring the slot has finished its job, you can use QMutex to control the access to the  QMap in each thread. The Qt help for QMutex clearly explains its usage; lock the mutex, do the work and then unlock.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there a particular reason for not using QThread? Is it running from a separate library?